# SvelteKit Rendering a Random Prop is different between server and client

Tags: javascript, server-side-rendering, svelte, sveltekit

I would like to make a component in SvelteKit which has a randomized parameter. The problem is that the value this parameter takes is different for when the page is rendered server-side versus when that page becomes hydrated.

For example, consider this component:

```html
<script>
    export let t = Math.random() * 90
    export let l = Math.random() * 90
</script>

<div class="box" style="--t: {t}vh; --l: {l}vw;"></div>

<style>
    .box {
        position: fixed;
        top: var(--t); left: var(--l);
        width: 10vw; height: 10vh;
        background-color: black;
        transition: all 1s;
    }
</style>
```

When the page is rendered on the server, `t` and `l` take on some random value, and the result is returned to the browser as HTML. However, once the page becomes hydrated, `t` and `l` take on different values. As a result, the box moves.

I don't want the box to move; rather, **I want the random value returned by the server to be used by the client as well** so there isn't a flash of changing style. Everything's fine if the page is navigated via the in-page router; it's when the page is server-rendered that the box moves.

The result is the same if I export a `load` function. Is there a way with SvelteKit for the server and client to agree on a random value?

Comment: I believe trying to reconcile server- and client-side values will be difficult if possible at all. I would instead prevent one or the other. You could set the values inside `onMount` to prevent server-side computation, or you could [turn hydration off](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#page-options-hydrate) for the page (it *has* to be a page however, not merely a component) to use server-side values (you'd have to also verify this doesn't negatively impact your client-side navigation behavior, though).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options here:

1. Set the random numbers in onMount so they're only set on the client. This will cause a FOUC, however, since the box won't be server rendered.

```svelte
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  let t, l;

  onMount(() => {
    t = Math.random() * 90;
    l = Math.random() * 90;
  })
</script>

{#if t && l }
<div class="box" style="--t: {t}vh; --l: {l}vw;"></div>
{/if}

<style>
    .box {
        position: fixed;
        top: var(--t); left: var(--l);
        width: 10vw; height: 10vh;
        background-color: black;
        transition: all 1s;
    }
</style>
```

2. Generate the random numbers inside a server endpoint that you fetch in the load function. Since SvelteKit caches the result of fetches inside load, this should use the same random numbers on both client and server.

```js
// random.json.js
export async function get() {
  return {
    body: {
      t: Math.random() * 90,
      l: Math.random() * 90,
    },
  };
}
```

```svelte
<!-- index.svelte -->
<script context="module">
  export async function load({ fetch }) {
    // this will be cached, so it will be the same on client & server
    const result = await fetch('/random.json');
    const { t, l } = await result.json();
    return {
      props: {
        t, l
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<script>
    export let t;
    export let l;
</script>

<div class="box" style="--t: {t}vh; --l: {l}vw;"></div>

<style>
    .box {
        position: fixed;
        top: var(--t); left: var(--l);
        width: 10vw; height: 10vh;
        background-color: black;
        transition: all 1s;
    }
</style>
```

Personally, I like the second option better, since there's no FOUC.

Comment: Nice, I didn't realize load worked that way, but now that I think about it it makes sense. Learned something new today ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think you could avoid a backend call and use a predictable pseudorandom number generator.

For example;
https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `.server.js`/`.server.ts` file to create `t` and `l` only on the server side.

You have a file `mypage.server.ts`:

```
export const load = async () => {
    return { t: Math.random() * 90, l: Math.random() * 90};
};
```

And then in `mypage.svelte`:

```
<script>
    export let data;
    let { t, l } = data;
</script>
...
```

See also :

- [Section in Svelte tutorial](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/page-data)
- [My commit fixing the same problem on my site](https://github.com/yairchu/soul-arithmetic/commit/92c9c084105912edbd662c94a1ae8365db7bf016)